# parsing a simple sentence using syntaxnet (on Ubuntu)

Tags: nlp, parsing

could someone help me in with the following. I would appreciate it.

I would like to use `syntaxnet` to analyze a sentence. I installed **Ubuntu** on windows following [this link](https://github.com/xzhaos/miscellaneous/wiki/Install-SyntaxNet-on-Windows-10).

What do I have to do next to make `syntaxnet` to produce result. The sentence is for example, "David put a book on shelf".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation from the Authors](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/syntaxnet/g3doc/syntaxnet-tutorial.md#detailed-tutorial-building-an-nlp-pipeline-with-syntaxnet) of SyntaxNet themselves (Google). That link shows all the main steps that you might want to do.

Looking at [the general setup required](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/syntaxnet), it seems like quite an involved process! I can't actually find any nice walkthroughs on how to really run and understand the models... only that first link above!

---

If you would like to simply parse sentences and are not tied to SyntaxNet, it might be worth looking into similar and (in my opinion) *easier to use* tools, such as [**spaCy**](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features). You can [install it easily](https://spacy.io/usage/) using one of the commands from their website:

[image]